# Finding maximum in itab without using the sort statement?

Tags: sorting, max, abap

Is there a way to find the maximum value `snocount` without using the `SORT` statement?

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ls_student1,
          snocount(5)  TYPE n,
          id           TYPE i,
          property(10) TYPE c,
          value(10)    TYPE c,
       END OF ls_student1.

DATA: wa1       TYPE ls_student1,
      lt_table4 TYPE HASHED TABLE OF ls_student1 with UNIQUE key snocount id.

lt_table4 = VALUE #(
        ( snocount = 1 id = 1 property = 'name'     value = 'rambo' )
        ( snocount = 4 id = 1 property = 'age'      value = '23' )
        ( snocount = 5 id = 1 property = 'college'  value = 'VIL' )
        ( snocount = 3 id = 1 property = 'phone no' value = '9599993451' )
        ( snocount = 8 id = 1 property = 'f name'   value = 'john whick' ) ).

LOOP AT lt_table4 INTO wa1.
  WRITE:/ wa1-snocount, wa1-id, wa1-property, wa1-value.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Are your looking for an **elegant solution** like pseudo code `max( x.snoucount for x in lt_table4 )`? Otherwise there's the boring option to declare `data snocount_max type n.` and then just loop over the table and store `if wa1-snocount gt snocount_max. snocount_max  = wa1-snocount. endif. `

Comment: @SandraRossi I think it's a valid question though. Maybe OP needs to keep the original order for some reason. Could still copy the entire table and sort the copy but that's a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: This is a valid, on-topic question. It's asking whether it's possible to achieve a specific outcome with specific criteria.

Comment: @SandraRossi As the answer by Florian shows, performance is a valid and real reason alone for asking this question. Assuming there is only one way to do something is rather myopic.

Comment: @mydoghasworms I agree with you and it's the third time someone tells me (just 3 years later), so I guess you want me to delete my comment. Done.

Answer (score 10):

Procedural:

```
DATA row_with_max_snocount TYPE ls_student1.
LOOP AT lt_table4 INTO DATA(candidate).
  IF candidate-snocount > row_with_max_snocount-snocount.
    row_with_max_snocount = candidate.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

Functional expression:

```
DATA(row_with_max_snocoun) =
  REDUCE ls_student1(
    INIT max = VALUE #( )
    FOR row IN lt_table4
    NEXT max = COND #(
      WHEN row-snocount > max-snocount
      THEN row
      ELSE max ) ).
```

Both take *c * n* steps to find the maximum. This is optimal in terms of computational theory if you do this once, and only for the maximum.

Sorting the table to find the maximum in general takes longer, *c * n * log n* steps. This is only worth it if you want to access multiple rows in order.

In case you need the minimum as well, there is a different algorithm that completes in *3/2 * c * n* steps.

For tables that have lots of columns, or that contain nested structures, consider using references `TYPE REF TO ls_student1` instead of variables `TYPE ls_student1` as they avoid copying around data in the main memory.

Comment: I am not entirely sure the second one is "functional". Functional programming is something completely different. Either way, nice answer and upvote from me.

Comment: True. I meant the “functional” here as it is being used in ABAP’s documentation: not as a synonym for functional programming, but as in “functional expression”.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to define the internal table as `SORTED` by `SNOWCOUNT` instead of `HASHED`:

```
      lt_table4 TYPE SORTED TABLE OF ls_student1 with UNIQUE key snocount id.
```

Hence, the last row of the primary key will contain the highest `SNOCOUNT` value:

```
DATA(row_with_max_snocount) = lt_table4[ lines( lt_table4 ) ].
```

If you want to keep the hashed key (because of performance for instance), you may define a secondary sorted index:

```
      lt_table4 TYPE HASHED TABLE OF ls_student1 with UNIQUE key snocount id
                WITH NON-UNIQUE SORTED KEY by_snocount COMPONENTS snocount.
```

Hence, the last row of the secondary key `BY_SNOCOUNT` will contain the highest `SNOCOUNT` value:

```
DATA(row_with_max_snocount) = lt_table4[ KEY by_snocount INDEX lines( lt_table4 ) ].
```